# Setting LINQ transaction a specified query (without SqlCommand)

Tags: linq, syntax, transactions

I was having difficulty specifying the title for the question properly - essentially I am getting an error saying "ExecuteReader requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized." for a situation similar to this:

```
using (db = getDbContext())
{
   var results = (from t in db.table
                  select t.column).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

As the error says, all this is already wrapped in another transaction, which I am trying to use for this query as well.

How can I specify the transaction using this query format?

I've tried creating an `SqlCommand("select column from table", myconnection, mytransaction)`,
which works, but I'd much rather use the LINQ syntax for the intellisense (amongst other) benefits, as the actual query is rather more complex

Many thanks, this has been annoying me for hours.

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the transaction into the context itself:

```
db.Transaction = theTransaction;
```

Comment: I just found this and came back here to ask if this is ok to do, excellent timing :)